# atomic<int> for older c++ compilers

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++11

I am using `atomic<int>` in my code, but the machine in which now I'm compiling has an older g++ version which doesn't support C++11. Is there any equivalent class available on the net, so that I can use it in my code, or if not, where I can find the C++11 implementation of `atomic<int>` so I can copy it from there. Can this be easily done?

Comment: `atomic<int>` as a library is useless without some support from the language, or lacking that, from the implementation.

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Tomalak, I din't ask anything about pthreads.

Comment: You can use Intel's Thread Building Blocks, it has atomic support.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: pthreads is an alternative. A good one.

Comment: Why C? Mixing the languages C and C++ is hard work. I suggest you do not try to do that unless you're doing it for fun.

Comment: Any function in gcc which provides atomic access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hans Boehm's atomic ops library](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/atomic_ops/) is good, although it's hard to determine what's available on various platforms.

If you're OK with the LGPL, [Intel TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has what you're looking for as well (plus a lot of other stuff).

If you're **only** looking at GCC, then you may be able to get away with just using [GCC's intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) (I'm not sure which version of GCC those showed up in, but they've been around for a while).

Answer (score 5):

The proposed (i.e. unofficial) [Boost.Atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/) library aims to do exactly this. I don't know what state it's in currently, but it's used in the implementation of the recently (*officially*) accepted [Boost.Lockfree](http://tim.klingt.org/boost_lockfree.tar.gz) library, so presumably it's usable.

---

**EDIT** — updated links, now that both Atomic and Lockfree have officially been in Boost for some time:
[Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/libs/atomic/)
[Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/libs/lockfree/)

Comment: @MetallicPriest : It's the link titled 'source code' on the page I linked to. ;-]

Answer (score 2):

[sig_atomic_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csignal/sig_atomic_t/)

> This is an integral type of an object that can be accessed as an
>   atomic entity, even in the presence of asynchronous signals.

in gcc is [atomic](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Atomic-Types.html)

> To avoid uncertainty about interrupting access to a variable, you can use a particular data type for which access is always atomic: sig_atomic_t.

Comment: I don't think sig_atmoic_t is atomic. It is just a volatile int.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: The documentation clearly states that it is atomic. And the name even has "atomic" in it. What more do you want?

Comment: Its atomic only if the code is running on a single core. When there are multicores, you need memory fences for atomicity, which volatile doesn't provide. Why would C++11 have atomic<int> if volatile was enough?

Comment: @MetallicPriest the word "volatile" is not on the documentation.

Comment: The processor will take care of the atomicity, @MetallicPriest, for small enough values. That's one reason for things like cache coherence. You only need a fence if you're going to be changing a value that's longer than the atomicity supported by the processor. If you had, say, 32 bytes and wanted to change them atomically you'd need a lock of some sort so you don't change 8 bytes and get swapped out, leaving an indeterminate value. The architecture assures that the size of a sig_atomic_t is small enough to be atomic on that CPU so any access is either the old or the new value.

Comment: On many architectures, a volatile int is atomic.  If that's all your architecture needs, that's what the library will supply.  That's why it's a good library (or one of the reasons).

Comment: @Paul Rubel, a fence does one additional thing: it prevents reordering of reads and writes, which can be a problem on multicore systems.

Comment: Even if reading and writing `sig_atomic_t` is atomic in a multithreading sense (apparently a promise that GCC makes; I can't say anything about other compilers), `++i` won't work correctly if `i` is a `sig_atomic_t`, but will if `i`'s a `std::atomic<int> i`.

Comment: Paul, x86 processors can reorder stores and loads, and volatile would not be enough for that. volatile is only for the compiler to stop reordering, not the processor.

Comment: MP, wrt volatile, I didn't make any arguments about re-ordering, the atomicity is orthogonal to the order. atomicity is one or the other, not some intermediate value.

Comment: @Metalic -- unlike the other architectures x86 is pretty safe when it comes to reordering: http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/